# sql ranking in access with filter

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi all I have a simple asp / access sql script that I would like to read from a table called projections for scores. The scores are entered with field called raceday. I have found the following sql on this site and adapted it to match my fields / table names.

```
SELECT tid ,tots,raceday, 1+  (SELECT COUNT(T1.tots)
FROM rankings  AS T1
WHERE T1.tots >T2.tots) AS Rank   FROM  rankings AS T2
ORDER BY tid asc
```

I need to find a way to filter by raceday and calculate rank of the records returned. 
The following code returns the records for raceday = 4 but it calculates rank on all the records.

```
SELECT tid ,tots, raceday, 1+ (SELECT COUNT(T1.tots)
FROM projections  AS T1
WHERE T1.tots >T2.tots) AS Rank   FROM projections AS T2
where raceday = '4'
ORDER BY tid asc
```

When returning the ranks on say 4 records the ranks would be 2,12,5,22

I would expect them to be 1, 2, 3, 4

I have also tried the where raceday = '4' statement  after the  > t2.tots section but it returns all the records

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to include the `where raceday = '4'` inside your sub query..

Comment: Thanks  @Mark C. for that I tried that  WHERE   raceday = '4'  and T1.tots > T2.tots ) AS Rank  I am getting the ranking by raceday but still getting the results for the other racedays being returned  I have tried adding the distinct racedays to the sql but it still return all records.

Comment: We would have to see the schema and some sample data for rankings and projections. I see 2 different tables in your question

Comment: Sorry I may have miss lead with a typo only using one table the actual table is projections I have put a result page here http://www.ttsportsbook.com/results.asp to demonstrate the data output from the SQL with the where raceday ='4'  in the sub query

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I added the raceday = ? to the main query as well as the sub query
SELECT raceday, tid ,tots, 1 + (SELECT COUNT(T1.tots)
FROM projections  AS T1
WHERE raceday = '4'  and T1.tots > T2.tots ) AS Rank  FROM projections AS T2
where raceday = '4' 
ORDER BY raceday  asc